# Java BufferedReader not reporting ready when it contains ">"

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I tried to ask this question earlier, but I was unclear in my question. [Java BufferedReader action on character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239740/java-bufferedreader-action-on-character)

Here is my problem..  I have a BufferedReader set to read from a device.  It is reading well.  I have it set to

```
if (Status.reader.ready()) {
    Lines = Status.reader.readLine();
}
if (Lines.contains(">")) {
    log.level1("ready to send data")
}
```

Buffered reader does not report the `>` until I've sent more data to the device. The problem is that when reader contains `>` it is not reporting ready.  It holds onto the `>` until I input more data.

I tried the following and it returns nothing.  It does not even return the log.level0()

```
Lines = ""

try {
    Lines = Status.reader.readLine();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.level0("Attempted to read blank line");
}
```

Here is the actual data sent:

```
^M^M01 02 F3^M00 01 F3 3E^M>
```

But BufferedReader ignores the `>` until more data has been sent then get a result like this:

```
>0102
```

When I check the actual data from the device from the command prompt, it returns what I'd expect, the `>` is present.

BufferedReader will not give me the `>`.  Is there some way I can check for this char otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

I recommend that you use the function **public int read() instead.**

At google you can find a lot of examples1

Answer (score 5):

The [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) method reads data a line at a time.  That is, it will attempt to read characters until it sees an end-of-line sequence (e.g. "\n", "\r" or "\r\n") or the end of stream.

If your input data is not line oriented, then you should not be using `readLine()` to read it.  I suggest that you do your own record / message extraction; e.g.

```
BufferedReader br = ...
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(...);
int ch = br.read();
while (ch != -1 && ch != '>') {
    sb.append((char) ch);
    ch = br.read();
}
String record = sb.toString();
```

Comment: That is a very long procedure which adds objects.   the final code ended up going from what it was to  a while loop with a (char)lines.read();

Comment: @Adam Outler - I don't understand what you are saying, or how it is relevant to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With those F3s in there it looks to me like your data isn't even character-oriented let alone line-oriented. Is your device really Unicode-compliant?

I would use a BufferedInputStream.

Comment: It transfers hex data with ^M delimiters.  Then it Requests data with >.  It's integer data.

Comment: Exactly, so you shouldn't be using a Reader at all. See above.

Comment: no, it works fine.  I just needed to use read instead of readline.  it is character oriented.  It is very much char oriented. 

Passing data through (char) read(); worked very well and changed my delmiters to \r instead of raw ^M

Comment: hexidecimal is a way of displaying chars.

Comment: This answer misses the point.  A device does not need to be Unicode compliant to produce data that you can read as characters in Java.  Simply use an InputStreamReader providing an explicit `encoding` argument to specify the stream's character encoding.